# How To iterate List[Result] and return one Boolean/Result?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a `Future[List[Result]]`
I need to run a logic for example if all items in the list are `Result.Ok` then return `Result.Ok` (or true), else return `Result.BadRequest` (or false)

I've tried:
  `futureResultList.map(temp => temp.forall(_ == true))`

But this code works only when the list contains booleans. It does not work if it contains `Result` objects (When changing check `to _ == Result.Ok`)

Comment: How do it ends with multiple `Result`? Using `Result` as a validation type seems weird to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To return a `Boolean` you just need to change the predicate in the `forall` call:

```
futureResultList.map(_.forall(_ == Result.Ok))
```

Comment: I tried that originally but it did not work with my syntax `temp => temp.forall(_ == Result.Ok)`. Other than learning to try both syntaxes next time, is there a place to read about the difference between them and why yours worked while my original syntax worked only for booleans?

Comment: My version is just more concise version of that code, so I'm not sure why your version did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to overview such an example is mapping. If you have a List of Result, but need a List of Boolean, then map it. Don't be afraid of mapping multiple times, it's way more readable in the long run :)

```scala
val futureResultList: Future[List[Result]] = ???
val futureBooleanList: Future[List[Boolean]] = futureResultList.map(_.map(_ == Result.OK))

val result = futureBooleanList.map(temp => temp.forall(_ == true))
```

or slightly more concise:

```scala
val futureResultList: Future[List[Result]] = ???
val result = futureResultList.map(_.map(_ == Result.OK)
    .forall(_ == true))
```

and of course as the other people suggest, go directly to checking the equality on the Result object. But mapping is often useful to navigate between types and getting a clearer and more readable code.